# Java issue on string manipulation - reversing text adds "null" onto the end

Tags: java, string

I am helping my son learn Java but I am not an experienced Java program. He has done a number of small challenges I set for him and his friend. The latest one had an issue and I don't know why. I asked them to create a small GUI with a JTextfield and a JButton. When someone presses the button the text in the text field must be reversed. The problem is when it is run the first time the program adds the text "null" onto the end of the text in the JTextfield. Subsequent button pushes does not add the text again but it stays in there anyway. I have included the code here:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReverseLetters {

    public static String oldString = "";
    public static String newString;
    public static int length;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel windowContent = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(fl);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encrypted Code");
        JTextField doodle = new JTextField(54);
        JButton Decrypt = new JButton("Decrypt");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        windowContent.add(doodle);
        windowContent.add(Decrypt);
        frame.setSize(625, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Decrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                oldString = doodle.getText();
                length = oldString.length();
                length--;
                for (int i = length; i > -1; i--) {
                    newString = newString + oldString.charAt(i);
                }

                doodle.setText(newString);
                newString = "";
                oldString = "";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to indent the code readably. (I've done it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: Also, meta commentary ('what a dumb restriction') is not useful and has no place in a question. Want to complain? Use meta.so. But the restriction is not arbitrary, it's there *for a reason*. SE has many years of experience running a site that's always, always, always under attack from spammers. They know a thing or two.

Comment: `What a dumb restriction. Completely arbitrary.` - no it's not. Think of bots/spammers that just create accounts for that. At least that way you'd have to put _some_ effort into SO first.

Comment: Because newString initialize with null when it is declared .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback:

Comment: I did indent the code but the code editor then told me I had not done it correctly so I though I had to ensure that all lines of code had to be indented by 4 spaces as the explanation was not clear.

Comment: I am not a spam bot - punishing me because of spam bots does not help me.

Comment: Should have mentioned earlier - thanks for indenting my code correctly. It was appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

that is because the variable `newString` has not been initialized. Thus, the value will be set with default null.

just set the `newString` variable with the `""` and you should be fine. :D

Answer (score 1):

Just Declare the second string like this:-

```
public static String newString = "";
```

Note:- When you declare a variable in java then only one reference will be created and that variable can't be used directly because it contain the default value(in String it will contain `null`), when we have to use use the variable directly in our application As per the good practice we should assign something.

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is this one:

`newString = newString + oldString.charAt(i);`

Essentially, the *concatenation* operator `+` requires that both arguments are actual strings, rather than `null` references. Currently `newString` is `null`.

A simple remedy is to initialise `newString` to empty: `public static String newString = "";`

In my humble opinion, this is one of the flaws in Java providing an symbolic operator for concatenation, and a `NullPointerException` should really be thrown rather than an arbitrary stringification of `null`ness.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed to know - I didn't realise a string initialises to null like that. I learned something, thank you.

Comment: *All* references initialise to `null` unless you tell them otherwise. `java.lang.String` is no different in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the code can be made to work by initialising newString, however by using local variables that are declared and initialized close to where they are used, the code can be made clearer and less error-prone than by using public static variables that can be modified by code anywhere in the program.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String newString = "";
            String oldString = doodle.getText();
            int length = oldString.length();

            for (int i = length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                newString = newString + oldString.charAt(i);
            }

            doodle.setText(newString);
        }
```

In this version you can see that all of the local variables are initialized before they are used; they don't have to be reset after use at the end of the method and they are "encapsulated" within the method so that they can't be modified by code outside of the actionPerformed method.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for that input, I am making some notes to take back to the boys to make sure they understand and I will include this so it is much appreciated. Regards, Martin.